# Eclipse, the AVR Plugin, and Arduino

Tags: eclipse, arduino, avr

I'm attempting to compile Arduino code in the Eclipse IDE using WinAVR and the AVR IDE plugin, and I'm running into one major stumbling block - when I try to compile the code I get the following error:

`/usr/bin/sh: g++: command not found
make: *** [main.o] Error 127`

Yeah, I bet not...I'm using Windows Vista.  I have the paths to WinAVR's avr-g++ all set correctly in the preferences tab, does anyone know why it might be doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Did you set your paths like this?

[avr preference panel http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/5996/avreclipsepath.png](http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/5996/avreclipsepath.png)

I followed the instructions on http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/Eclipse and everything worked fine on my Vista box with Eclipse 3.5.

Comment: Thanks for your response, and sorry for the delay in my reply.  I tried setting it up as you have it in your screenshot; unfortunately when I try to select a custom path to those folders in my arduino directory I get an "Invalid Path" error from Eclipse.

Comment: Do you have spaces in your directory?

Comment: Nah - I tried pointing it at the above directories after unzipping a copy of the arduino 0018 environment, unmodified.  Still getting an "Invalid Path" error.  It will only allow me to use the path to my "WinAVR" directory, and when it uses that it tries to do the Linux like thing above and gives an error on compile.  Maybe uninstalling the copy of WinAVR will help?

Comment: I didn't have to install winavr on my box. May-be your system PATH is fubar ?

Comment: what version is your make.exe? recently, the cygwin gnu version 3.81 stopped supporting windows path names -- and totally broke my eclipse CDT. The fix was to grab the MinGW version of make.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way now to use arduino in eclipse is by using the arduino eclipse plugin.
It is build on the same software stack CDT +win AVR but it sets all the options correctly for you. It even comes with a library import functionality.
Look at [eclipse.baeyens.it](http://eclipse.baeyens.it) for installation instructions an FAQ.